# Unity Hub on Linux "Not enough space" download error

Tags: unity, linux

I just downloaded and installed the official Unity Hub app on my Ubuntu machine. However, when I try to download the latest version of the editor, an error message pops up:

> ⚠ There is not enough space to download and install the selected items

I tried to change the install location of the Hub but without success. How can I download the Unity Editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Linux environment, temporary downloads are first stored in the `/tmp` folder and then moved to the destination directory. Downloads fail to start if the estimated free space for that folder isn't enough, especially when there are system partitions.

User *apollongt* on Reddit explains a convenient solution to the issue [in this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/f6h2y1/linux_unity_hub_not_enough_space/). I'm assuming the installation directory wasn't changed (the standard directory is `~/Unity/Hub/`):

1. Create a folder named `tmp` in your Home directory (Bash command: `mkdir ~/tmp`).
2. Navigate to the folder where the `UnityHub.AppImage` is and open in Terminal (or, Bash: `cd ~/Unity/Hub`).
3. Execute the following command from the Terminal: `TEMP=~/tmp ./UnityHub.AppImage`.

The Unity Hub will open, and you'll be able to download the Editor. This way, you're telling the Hub to use `~/tmp` in Home as a temporary location for downloads rather than `/tmp` (note the missing '`~`', short for the Home directory).